# Jquery Search Function not highlighting text

Tags: jquery, search, highlight

I've got this search function which I intend to highlight the value of the input text on a search box within the div of a content box. The only problem is that it is not working. When the function is called I get the console.log of 'wording...' but no errors or highlights. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
function search() {
//highlight text
  var o = { words: $('#searchInput').val() };
  highlight('#searchtextone', o);

  function highlight(id, options) {
    var o = {
        words: '',
        caseSensitive: false,
        wordsOnly: true,
        template: '$1$2$3',
        class: 'highlight',
        background: 'lightskyblue',
        color: 'black'
      },
      pattern;
    $.extend(true, o, options || {});

    if (o.words.length == 0) {
      console.log('no words');
      return;
    }
    pattern = new RegExp(
      '(>[^<.]*)(' + o.words + ')([^<.]*)',
      o.caseSensitive ? '' : 'ig'
    );

    $(id).each(function() {
      var content = $(this).html();
      if (!content) return;
      $(this).html(content.replace(pattern, o));
      // $("#searchtextone").addClass("highlight");
      console.log('wording...');
    });
  }
}
```

HTML - Input

```
<input id="searchInput" onkeyup="search()" class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search"><i type="reset" class="fas fa-search"></i></input>
```

HTML - Content

```
<p id="searchtextone" class="searchtext searchtextone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a workaround to this problem. I used this library:
https://github.com/yjseo29/highlight.js

My code is as follows

```
var searchCnt = 0;

var option = {
  color: "black",
  background: "lightskyblue",
  bold: false,
  class: "high",
  ignoreCase: true,
  wholeWord: false
};

var originalContent = $("#searchtextone").html();
searchCnt = $("#searchtextone").highlight($("#searchInput").val(), option);
$("#matcheCnt").text(searchCnt);

$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
  $("#searchtextone").html(originalContent);
  $("#searchInput").val(this.value);
  if (this.value == "") return;
  searchCnt = $("#searchtextone").highlight(this.value, option);
  $("#matcheCnt").text(searchCnt);
});
```

I hope that this will help the next person that might have a similar problem

Comment: This only works on one selector. I am trying to work out how to get it working on multiple content fields.

Comment: This works on multiple content divs:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836522/highlight-text-in-multiple-content-divs-from-input